# AWS change record set to private ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm trying to write a script that would allow the instances to update a record set in AWS each time a new one is spun up.
I'm following this guide:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/simple-resource-record-route53-cli/

My sample.json looks like this:

```
{
        "Comment": "CREATE/DELETE/UPSERT a record ",
        "Changes": [{
        "Action": "UPSERT",
                    "ResourceRecordSet": {
                                "Name": "test.mydomain.com",
                                "Type": "A",
                                "TTL": 300,
                             "ResourceRecords": [{ "Value": "4.4.4.4"}]
  }}]
}
```

I want to replace the `4.4.4.4` but with instance's private IP address.
I tried inserting `$IP_ADDRESS` there, but obviously, it didn't work.

I also tried entering this manually by doing this:

```
IP_ADDRESS=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id HKJA837HJS --change-batch {"Comment": "UPSERT a record", "Changes": [{"Action": "UPSERT", "ResourceRecordSet":{"Name":"test.mydomain.com","Type":"A","TTL":300,"ResourceRecords":[{"Value":"$IP_ADDRESS"}]}}]}
```

When I do this I keep getting the following error:

```
Unknown options: Changes:, [{Action:, UPSERT,, ResourceRecordSet:Name:test.mydomain.com}]}, ResourceRecordSet:Type:A}]}, ResourceRecordSet:TTL:300}]}, ResourceRecordSet:ResourceRecords:[{Value:}]}]}, UPSERT a record,
```

I tried re-formatting this numerous times but there's always something wrong.
How can I make sure the instance's IP address is inserted in that recordset each time a new instance in launched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to pass JSON via the command line is very difficult to get correct because of the need to escape your quote marks.

Instead put your json into a file. Execute a command like this:

```
sed "s/4.4.4.4/$NEWIP/g" update_rr.json
aws --profile PROD route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ABCDEFGH012345 --change-batch file://update_rr.json
```

Comment: I tried this however when I use the file I cannot change the `"Value": "4.4.4.4"` bit to a variable with the instance's private IP address.

Comment: You will need to preprocess the file to change the value. I use the unix program `sed` to do this. The CLI does not support variables. This is a shell convention. Example: `sed -i 's/4.4.4.4/$NEWIP/g' update_rr.json`

Comment: It worked! Thank you John. Just to add to your comment, in order to add a variable you need to use double quotes. If you edit the answer I will mark it as solution. Cheers.